# do you need spritesheets for a small scale games

Tags: winforms, sprite, 2d-games, sprite-sheet

For the past days, ive been using the xna library and it methods etc to get frame of a SpriteSheet too create an animation in a default windows form, little did I know It would never work because I did not have methods likes "LoadContent" "Update" "Draw" which could only be used with Xna forms in which I did not have because xenia isn't supported for windows 10. It was a huge bummer, and my frustration got me thinking do I really need sprite sheets?. I could easily just get each frame out of the SpriteSheet myself using resource such as paint.net, modify them as necessary and using a time interval, respectively create an animation. So down to my question. Do I really need sprite sheets for small scale games.

Just to clarify what I mean by "small scale games" .... games that are made not necessarily to be played by other people but more as being made for fun or for learning. For example - the first game a person might make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of a sprite sheet is to make the transfer and loading of assets easier. It's a little harder to load 20 files based on some name pattern than it is to load a single file by name.

Sometimes there are other benefits to sprites like number of file opens/requests, optimizations for textures... but running locally with a decent engine, you shouldn't have to worry about any of that.

On the web, CSS sprites are used to combined tens of images into a single file as to reduce the number of requests the browser makes to a server. This probably isn't applicable to your situation but there may be similar considerations. Either way, the impact is minimal if you're doing it for a personal project.

If you are okay with loading a bunch of files into frames, then that seems like a good way forward.

Comment: What do you mean in this sentence? "Sometimes there are other benefits to sprites like number of file opens/requests". I just cant comprehend what you mean.

Comment: This is more of a side question, if the browser makes less requests which means lower ping, the computer would have to do more "work" load the images because now it has to find that specific image that it needs in this single image file  which means higher fps ... right? So In a general scenario which would be better less ping and higher fps or vice versa

Comment: Browsers only fulfill 6 requests at a time. It's the roundtrip time and this queue that delay the loading, it's not the actual transfer size.

Splitting the files on the CPU is likely less work than loading files separately. Once they are loaded there is no increase in speed, it would all be at load and the FPS would not change (unless you were loading all the assets every frame)

Comment: ahh, I see. Well, thank you sir, for your time and information. It is and will be greatly appreciated.